# Isotope stability in alkali vs alkaline earth metals

Tags: nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

Why do alkaline earth metal atoms (and those with similar atomic structure, like Yb and Cd) have more stable isotopes than alkali metal atoms?

Comment: Tin has more stable isotopes than any other element, but is not an alkali metal.

Comment: @JonCuster: Thanks, but I'm not sure how that information is relevant. The question is why there are more stable isotopes of alkaline earths than of alkalis. This has nothing to do with carbon group atoms.